# Check whether s1 has the prefix/suffix AAA and assign the result to a boolean variable b

Tags: java, string, prefix, suffix-array

Hello here is the question.

1. Check whether s1 has the prefix AAA and assign the result to a boolean variable b
2. Check whether s1 has the prefix AAA and assign the result to a boolean variable b

This is what I have so far

```
/**
 *
 * @author samue_000
 */
public class N95e {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "Welcome";
        String s2 = "welcome";
        boolean b = true;
        s1.lastIndexOf("AAA");



        if (s1.lastIndexOf("AAA") == true) {

        }
        System.out.println(s1.lastIndexOf("AAA"));

    }

}
```

Really stuck on this and mind has gone blank. So help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you looking for `startsWith`?

Comment: Both of your points are the same. Shouldn't point 2 be about suffix instead of prefix?

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isStartAAA = s1.startsWith("AAA");
boolean isEndAAA = s1.endsWith("AAA");
```

Then print both values, you can achieve this with `indexOf()` as well but it unnecessary usage of the same.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I got it now

just do `boolean b = s1.startsWith("AAA);`

then print

Answer (score 0):

Or even more compact:

```
System.out.println(s1.startsWith("AAA")||s1.endsWith("AAA"));
```